# question abou equals method for objects from self made class

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

So , i took this screenshot from a mooc fi course , this is about defining a equals method to check the equality of the objects of your class.
my question is, in the below screenshot , if first check if (object calling the method == object passed into method as parameter) . if true it will return true , then check if the object passed as parameter is an instance of the class , if not the method will return false but it keep going executin the next line where it uses type cast to convert the object to the class type ? how? im a newbie so i dont understand how it doesnt return false and keep executing method in question's next line.
if (!(object instanceof class)) evaluates as true, shouldnt the method return false ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The comments tell you exactly what is going on, first it checks if `compared` is of type `Person`. If it isn't, it immediately returns `false`. If the next statement is reached, then `compared` is of type `Person` and can safely be cast to `Person`. What part is confusing?

Comment: so the object is 100% Object-type so we pass the parameter as (Object compared) , if compared is not type of Person class , method return false and if compared is instantiated of Person it will execute next line? the confusing thing for me is if compared is already of type Person (becasue the previous if was false) so why we should use type casting to convert it to type Person? isnt it already a Person object?

ps thank you for your help

Comment: Every object in Java is 100% Object-type. `Object o = 1;` `if (o instanceof Integer)` is `o` of type `Integer`? `if (!(o instanceof Integer))` is `o` **not** of type `Integer`? The method signature is a direct consequence of `Object#equals(Object)`. Every reference type in Java inherits from `Object` as the root of the type hierarchy. And that means the `equals(Object)` method must be overridden from that primordial type when you want more than reference equality.

Comment: if **(!( compared instanceof Person))** evaluates to false, it means compared is type Person , but because compared passed to the method as **(Object compared)** and not **(Person compared)** we should type cast it to Person? am i right?

Comment: What do you mean by *evaluates to false*? Note there is a negation operator in the evaluation, so the "evaluates to false" is a "double negative". Which is confusing in English. It says if `compared` is **not** of type `Person`. So if that evaluates to `false` then `compared` **is** of type `Person`.

Comment: sorry for bad english. yeah i mean if `(!(compared instanceof Person))` is not `true` then it doesnt return `false` , which means the object `compared` is type `Person` but why we still type-cast `compared` to `Person` is because `compared` is passed to the method as `(Object compared)` and  not `(Person compared)` .  it actually the type casting is that confused me.

Comment: Because of [`Object#equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)); I already said that. Read the linked JavaDoc. You can't change the signature of `Object#equals(Object)` to `Object#equals(Person)`. You can't cast an `Object` to a `Person` without checking if it is in fact a `Person` (which it could be). Every `Person` is an `Object`, not every `Object` is a `Person`.

Comment: oh thank you so much , im a newbie and i really should study much more. i got my answer at **You can't cast an Object to a Person without checking if it is in fact a Person** . thanks.

Comment: The key thing to understand is that casting does not change the class of an object. It takes a _reference_ of one type and converts to a new reference of a subtype. You can only cast an object to a type that it actually has at runtime.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) -- in the future, upload the _text_ of your code, not just an image of your code; that way people can run or edit it themselves without needing to retype.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!(compared instanceof Person))`, where `!` can be described as **negation** or the **logical NOT** operator, which returns `true` if value is `false` and `false` if value is `true`. So what the **NOT** operator is doing here is converting `if(!(true))` to `if(false)` and vice versa. Therefore, first it gets the return value of `compared instanceof Person` then it negates the returned value. So when the value of `compared instanceof Person` is `false` then only the method will return `false`.